# tkinter Message widget relief option not working

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm creating a Minesweeper GUI in Python, and I can't decide to use a Label or Message widget for the tiles. I want to apply the relief option 'RAISED' for each tile in the game, but that option does not work in the Message widget. But if I use the Label widget, the numbers in the boxes aren't centered, despite using the justify option, but relief works. How do I use relief in the Message widget? If it is not possible, how do I center text in a Label widget? Here is my code so far:

```
import random

try: # ensures usage of best GUI package on computer
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter import Message
    from tkinter.ttk import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

class Board:

    def __init__(self, width, height, numBombs):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.bombs = numBombs
        self.boxlist = []
        for i in range(width * height):
            a = Message(relief = 'raised', justify = 'center')
            a.grid(column = (i + 1) % width, row = (i + 1) // width, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
            if i == width * height - 1:
                a.grid(row = 0, column = 0, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
            a.bind('<Button-1>', self.reveal)
            self.boxlist.append(a)
        self.reallist = ['0'] * width * height

    def reveal(self, event):
        event.widget['text'] = self.reallist[self.boxlist.index(event.widget)]

a = Board(5, 6, 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

justify=
Defines how to align multiple lines of text. Use LEFT, RIGHT, or CENTER. **Note that to position the text inside the widget, use the anchor option**. Default is CENTER. (justify/Justify)

Justify does not change the position of the text in the label, the anchor option does that and it is set as CENTER by default, but why if your text still not centered ?

When you create a label and you don't specify its width explicitly using width="X", the label is created with a width equal to the length of its text, so there is no place for the text to move.

If you set a custom width larger than that of text length you will notice the text is now centered.

Taking '|' to be the limits of the label:

```
ttk.Label(root, text="hello world") 
|hello world|

ttk.Label(root, text="hello world", width=17) 
|   hello world   |
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be working but you have not expanded the borderwidth so you can not see it. Try this to see the pronounced effect:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Message
from tkinter import Frame
tk = tkinter.Tk()
root = tk
Frame1 = Frame(root, borderwidth= 50)
Frame1.grid()
mymessage=Message (Frame1, relief='raised',anchor='center', text="test",  bd=20)
mymessage.grid(padx= 20, pady= 20)
root.mainloop()
```